# Cryptic error message in emacs org-mode following attempted export of file containing image-generating block of R code

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode, literate-programming

I have an R code block that generates an image (see below). Executing the code is no problem (i.e., C-c C-c from within the block generates an image temp.png as expected). However, on export to PDF via LaTeX, there is an error message:

```
org-babel-sha1-hash: Wrong number of arguments: called-interactively-p, 1
```

The only other reference to this error (sans the bit about sha1) is from here, [Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_byte_compile_problem.html) in a very diffirent context.

The code block closely follows the example from this previous question [Embedding R plots in Latex via org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980326/embedding-r-plots-in-latex-via-org-mode)
Here's the code:

```
#+NAME: optimal_applications 
#+BEGIN_SRC R  :results graphics :file temp.png :exports both  
require(ggplot2) 
c <- c(.01, .05, .10) 
df <- data.frame(q =
  rep((0:100)/100, length(c)), 
c = c(sapply(c, function(x) rep(x,  101))) )

df$s.star <- with(df, log(-c/log(1-q))/log(1-q))
df$s.star[df$s.star < 0] <- 0

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = q, y = s.star, colour=factor(c))) + geom_line(aes(group=factor(c))) +
    xlab("Probability that an application is successful") +
    ylab("Optimal number of applications to send")
print(g) 
#+END_SRC
```

**Update:** org-mode & emacs version

```
Org-mode version 7.8.03 (release_7.8.03.267.g1c8eb)
GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.4) of 2011-04-04 on crested, modified by Debian
```

Comment: I think Its not at all related to `R`, But IIRC its backward incomparable change in emacs 24. full debugger message would help to see where is the problem. and please update which version of emacs and org-mode you are using

Comment: Thanks - done. Do you think running emacs 24 might be a solution?

Comment: I just tried your example and it works for me just fine.  Your org is newer than mine (release_7.8.02.58.g013b) but my Emacs is newer than yours (23.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.5)
 of 2011-08-14 on rothera, modified by Debian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After learning that G.Jay Kerns couldn't reproduce with a newer version of Emacs, I upgraded to Emacs 24.0.91.1 and the problem was resolved. FWIW, https://superuser.com/questions/296013/how-do-i-upgrade-emacs-to-the-current-version-on-ubuntu has short tutorial on how to build Emacs from the repository that proved useful.